# Adding date exceptions to an opening hours script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for being a complete novice, but I am struggling a bit with my home-brewed script and I hope someone can help me out.

What I want to achieve: I would like to display some business opening hours. The opening hours are the same every week except for some exceptions – holidays – where I need to display something else.

I got this far, but I can not seem to get past the exception variable, so I am doing something wrong :)

```js
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();

var hours = ['Monday hours', 'Tuesday hours', 'Wednesday hours', 'Thursday hours', 'Friday hours', 'Saturday hours', 'Sunday hours'];
var exception = 'Special day';

var w42y2022 = new Date('2022-10-17');
var w52y2022 = new Date('2022-12-26');
var w01y2023 = new Date('2023-01-02');


if ([w42y2022.getDay(), w52y2022.getDay(), w01y2023.getDay()].includes(d.getDay())) {
  document.getElementById("openinghours").innerHTML = exception;
} else {
  document.getElementById("openinghours").innerHTML = hours[n-1];
}
```

```html
<div id="openinghours">
</div>
```

Comment: you must take into account the GMT offset of your time zone.
all computers make their calculations based on a GMT 0 for all the dates they handle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I think I solved it on my own by changing `getDay` to `getDate` in the if statement:

```
if ([w42y2022.getDate(), w52y2022.getDate(), w01y2023.getDate()].includes(d.getDate())) {
  document.getElementById("openinghours").innerHTML = exception;
} else {
  document.getElementById("openinghours").innerHTML = hours[n-1];
}
```